Select query returning -1 SQL
I have been trying to query a postgres database.
Once the query is executed, it's returning a value as -1.
This is the code:
string connString = $"Server={Host};Username={User};DataBase={DBname};Port={Port};Password={Password}";            

using (var conn = new NpgsqlConnection(connString))
{
    Console.Out.WriteLine("Opening connection");
    conn.Open();

    using (var command = new NpgsqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM history.optimizations", conn))
    {
        var countOfRows = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        Console.Out.WriteLine("counting the rows");
    }
}

Tried changing the connection string and other parameters.

You don't use ExecuteNonQuery for SELECT queries. That SELECT will return a 1 row, 1 column result set with the count in it. It should be ExecuteScalar()'d. ExeuteNonQuery is for insert, update and delete, whereupon the result is the number of rows affected (usually)
